# Is it possible to verify and publish a contract with openzeppelin imports without uploading imported contracts?

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, erc-721, openzeppelin, polygon

I wrote a contract and imported below contracts and deployed into polygon testnet, but while verifying and publish it is getting failed with :
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

could you please suggest what can be done?[image: I am getting error like this]

Comment: You need to have those @openZeppelin contracts in your folder so you can compile the code in the first place. Did you manage to compile the code without error?

Comment: Use plugins to do that. Manually will never works

Comment: U use node_modules, right? Here it seems it didn't have those @OpenZeppelin contracts to import.

Comment: I have compiled the contract in remixIDE and deployed it from the same

Comment: Yes it got compiled perfectly in Remix